# What difference does it make if the double brackets of a nested list comes before its dollar sign?

Tags: r, list, nested, purrr

What difference does it make if the double brackets [[i]] comes before the dollar sign $ in a nested list? I am curious to know what difference it makes in terms of attempting to unnest the list.

What is the difference between

```
nested_list[[i]]$element
```

and

```
nested_list$element[[i]]
```

?

I'm especially curious because my unnested list is the former case, whereas one tutorial (linked below) about unnesting lists using purrr's modify_depth function has the latter case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d-5isplHV4

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the first case you are first extracting the ith member of list `nested_list`, which can be named or not. Then you extract a named member, `element`. In the second case you first extract a named member, `element`. Then extract the ith member of the sub-list `element`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, we are selecting the `i`th list element and then extract the element named "element"

In the second, it is extracting an "element" and then get the `i`th value.  Here, `i` can be a variable or an index.  But `$i` assumes that there is a element with name `i`

```
lst1 <- list(hello = 1:3, world =  list(element = 2:4))
i <- "world"
# or it can be
# i <- 2

lst1[[i]]$element
#[1] 2 3 4
```

Now, we check the second case

```
lst2 <- list(element = list(hello = 1:3), another = 4:6)
i <- 1
lst2$element[[i]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

If we do

```
lst2$element$i # it won't work because there is no element named 'i'
 #NULL
```

Comment: Thank you to both akrun and @Rui Barradas. Other than creating my own loop function, do you know a function, like purrr's modify_depth, that could help me unnest a list such as the first case above?

Comment: @WillM Depends on the values in the list and how deep your nesting are.  One option is `unnest` or `unnest_wider` etc.

Comment: @WillM Without a small reproducible example, it is so difficult to give a specific answer because `list` nesting can be totally different and diverse with elements either vector or data.frame etc.